# Moving keyframes out of Vector Motion in Premiere

Tags: keyframes, premiere-pro, motion-graphics

I'm working on a project and have created a graphic layer with text on it. I added some keyframes for position to move the text over time. then I added another text that need its own distinct position animation. but because I had added position keyframes in Vector Motion, now both of them are effected. my question is how to copy and paste the keyframes of position in Vector Motion into the position of one of the text.

I tried edit>copy but when I paste it, it goes under Vector motion not the transform part of the text I want.

What should I do. And notice I don't want to add another graphic layer for the new text